# How to switch the rendering to be with or without OculusRift Effect?

Tags: three.js

I am having trouble while writing the OculusRift Effect. Here is the situation

```
function init(){
                 .
                 .
                 .


  if(k==true){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    console.log(renderer.getClearColor());

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    effect = new THREE.OculusRiftEffect( renderer );
    effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    console.log(effect.getHMD().interpupillaryDistance);



  }
  if(k==false){

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    console.log(renderer.getClearColor());

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  }
}
```

While I am switching between "k==false" and "k==true"(the initial k is false) by pressing a key button, how am I supposed to correctly switch the rendering to be with and without the effect of OculusRiftEffect?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have two renderers I think. I am not sure but most of the post-processing effects i used had an "effect.enable" which you can then set to true or false, thus switchting the effect itself on and off instead of swichting renderers in your case.